# How to make progress bar and load database running together in splash screen?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, progress-bar, splash-screen

I have splash screen which can load database sqlite before go to main activity. And my problem, progress bar layout run after loaded database. If we lauch app, app become blank layout (load database) -> progress bar running -> main activity. So, how to make progress bar and load database running together in splash screen?

IntroActivity.java:

```
public class IntroActivity extends Activity implements LoadingTaskFinishedListener {
private SQLiteDatabase db = null;
private DataKamus datakamus = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    datakamus = new DataKamus(this);
    db = datakamus.getWritableDatabase();
    datakamus.createTable(db);
    datakamus.generateData(db);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);
     new Loading(progressBar, this).execute("");

}

@Override
public void onTaskFinished() {
    completeSplash();
}
private void completeSplash(){
    startApp();
    finish(); // Don't forget to finish this Splash Activity so the user can't return to it!
}
private void startApp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Loading.java:

```
public class Loading extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {
public interface LoadingTaskFinishedListener {
    void onTaskFinished();
}

private final ProgressBar progressBar;
private final LoadingTaskFinishedListener finishedListener;

public Loading(ProgressBar progressBar,
        LoadingTaskFinishedListener finishedListener) {
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
    this.finishedListener = finishedListener;
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    Log.i("Tutorial", "Starting task with url: " + params[0]);
    if (resourcesDontAlreadyExist()) {
        downloadResources();
    }
    return 1234;

}

private boolean resourcesDontAlreadyExist() {

    return true;
}

private void downloadResources() {

    int count = 25;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        int progress = (int) ((i / (float) count) * 100);
        publishProgress(progress);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    finishedListener.onTaskFinished();
}
```

Comment: Put     db = datakamus.getWritableDatabase();
    datakamus.createTable(db);
    datakamus.generateData(db); in your doInBackground.

Comment: I put in like this:

 protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
  db = datakamus.getWritableDatabase();
  datakamus.createTable(db);
  datakamus.generateData(db);
  if (resourcesDontAlreadyExist()) {
   downloadResources();
  }
  return 1234;
 }

But if running, database fail to load.

Comment: datakamus.createTable(db); datakamus.generateData(db);  

Are you trying to pass db object like this? Why ?

And if you don't put those lines in async, is that working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IntroActivity, with change in Loding constructor,

```
public class IntroActivity extends Activity implements LoadingTaskFinishedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

    ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);
     new Loading(progressBar, this, IntroActivity.this).execute("");

}

@Override
public void onTaskFinished() {
    completeSplash();
}
private void completeSplash(){
    startApp();
    finish(); // Don't forget to finish this Splash Activity so the user can't return to it!
}
private void startApp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(IntroActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

And your async class,

```
public class Loading extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer> {
public interface LoadingTaskFinishedListener {
    void onTaskFinished();
}

private SQLiteDatabase db = null;
private DataKamus datakamus = null;

private final ProgressBar progressBar;
private final LoadingTaskFinishedListener finishedListener;

public Loading(ProgressBar progressBar,
        LoadingTaskFinishedListener finishedListener, Context context) {
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
    this.finishedListener = finishedListener;
    this.datakamus = new DataKamus(context);
}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
    /*
     * database
     */
    db = datakamus.getWritableDatabase();
    datakamus.createTable(db);
    datakamus.generateData(db);

    Log.i("Tutorial", "Starting task with url: " + params[0]);
    if (resourcesDontAlreadyExist()) {
        downloadResources();
    }
    return 1234;

}

private boolean resourcesDontAlreadyExist() {

    return true;
}

private void downloadResources() {

    int count = 25;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        int progress = (int) ((i / (float) count) * 100);
        publishProgress(progress);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    finishedListener.onTaskFinished();
}
}
```

See, if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You should move all your database loading code to your asynctask.